# Make -Wshadow ignore initializer list

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning, shadowing

In a large project I recently discovered a problem with shadowing member variables. To avoid those in the future, I wanted to introduce -Wshadow to show those kind of problems. However most of the constructors look like this:

```
struct Foo{
  int bar1, bar2;
  Foo(int bar1, int bar2): bar1(bar1), bar2(bar2){}
}
```

Which is nice and convenient but of course makes the compiler issue the warning so I get spamed with warnings at those places. Of course I could change the parameter names or the member variables (but what should they be called? A "bar1" already describe the name perfectly...) But as this is a lot of work distracting from the actual problem I'd rather like to have gcc ignore initializer lists for now.

Is there any flag/option/... which behaves like Wshadow but ignores initializer lists?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily ignore the warnings using [GCC's diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

```
struct Foo{

  int bar1, bar2;

  #pragma GCC diagnostic push
  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow"
  Foo(int bar1, int bar2)
  :bar1{bar1}
  ,bar2{bar2}
  {}
  #pragma GCC diagnostic pop

};
```